# How to track down all the registers connected to a specific downstream register? (for set_max_delay's --from)

Tags: flipflop, timing-analysis, cdc, sdc

The Xilinx Vivado's `set_max_delay` requires `-from` to be set.

Basically I'd like to set max delay *TO* a register.
Because there can be lots of registers source to my destination register, I don't know their name.

- `set_max_delay 3 -datapath_only -to [get_cells dest_reg*]` isn't valid because it doesn't have `-from` option.

### My plan

- Get all the input pins (`D, CE, R`) of the destination register

  - `set dest_pins [get_pins -of_objects $dest -filter {REF_PIN_NAME == "D" || REF_PIN_NAME == "CE" || REF_PIN_NAME == "R"}]`
  - The danger is that there might be other input pins...
- Get all the nets connected to these input pins

  - `set nets [get_nets -segments -of_objects $dest_pins]`
- Track down all the output pins connected to these nets

  - `set source_pins [get_pins -of_objects $nets -filter {IS_LEAF && DIRECTION == "OUT"}]`
- Get all the registers of these pins

  - `set source [get_cells -of_objects $source_pins]`

This looks too overkill just to add a CDC constraint on a single register.

#### Question

- What's the best way of adding a constraint using only its name and nothing else?

Comment: Did you try `-from [get_cells *]` and `-from [get_ports in[*]]` to include all input ports and registers sourcing your destination register?

Comment: I believe that has a more or less big impact on the processing time. I tend to avoid wildcard.

Comment: Not sure if your claim about "processing time about wildcards" is true cz I never came across that. This is what people do normally. Nobody writes 10000 SDC lines for 10000 signals that fan into a register. Even if you do, the amount of effort synthesiser has to put is the same as you put a wildcard. Cz the no. of constraints to be solved by the Synthesiser in both cases is the same = 10000.

Comment: I believe that has something to do with the database, wildcard queries are always heavier. Wildcard is O(n) while the way I do it should be maximum O(log n).  Your answer is still valid to add quickly the constraint and it works! Thanks!

Comment: I shall put it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dest_reg` is the full hierarchial name of the destination register, then you can add two constraints to your SDC:

To constraint ALL paths from different input ports to your destination register:

```
set_max_delay -from [get_ports in [*]] -to [get_cells dest_reg] <delay>
```

To constraint ALL paths from different registers to your destination register:

```
set_max_delay -from [get_cells [*]] -to [get_cells dest_reg] <delay>
```

**EDIT**:

As in Vivado the above second command generates warnings as the wildcard generates unsupported paths as well, so registers have to be explicitly mentioned for `get_cells` . In Altera, `get_registers` can be used, in Vivado it is not supported, so a work around is needed for `get_cells`. Since registers follow the naming convention `_reg` in the netlist :

```
set_max_delay -from [get_cells *_reg*] -to [get_cells dest_reg] <delay>
```

Comment: Actually I just tested and I get thousands of warnings listing all the cells (not only regs) possible in my design `is not a valid startpoint`. `get_cells *` is not appropriate. Also `-hierarchical` is necessary.

Comment: What is the warning message?

Comment: `[Constraints 18-402] set_max_delay: '*' is not a valid startpoint. ["/home/alexis/git/constraints.tcl":10]` can be instances, LUTs, FFs ...

Comment: Might be Altera specific. Can you try 'get_registers' then, instead of 'get_cells'. Or did you forget the square brackets [] ?

Comment: no that's xilinx, get_cells is correct. It just tries all the cells existing in my design.

Comment: 'get registers [*] ' filters only the registers to be specific, in Altera. I never tried 'get_registers' in Vivado though.

Comment: Regs have `_reg` in the name.

Comment: Then you can manipulate the wildcard accordingly. I think Vivado supports only get_cells, not get_registers, so may need a work around. In Vivado `-from [get_cells *_reg*/C] ... -to [get_cells *_reg*/D]`

Comment: However this is for current hierarchy. You need hierarchial flag as you mentioned above. If you are talking about instances within.

Comment: Did it work?...

Comment: `get_cells -hierarchy *_reg*` works. You're selecting pins (C and D), that's wrong. Sometimes the compiler uses `CE and/or R` pins, not covered by your command.

Comment: So simply wildcard on 'reg' removes warnings? I guess Vivado is smart enough to figure out the correct pins then. Cz for eg: 'D' is not a valid start point for -from flag, hence explicitly mentioned the clock pin C.

Comment: yes because only registers (and clocks) are valid startpoints, an LUT isn't. Vivado isn't smart enough. If your constraint is on a specific pin, it will never use a different pin. That's why we all tend to avoid using pins for constraints. Rather, using a cell uses the vivado's potential.

Comment: However there is a catch while using 'hierarchical' flag, not sure if you are aware of it. Vivado doesn't recommend its usage. Refer chapter 2 of UG903 guide.

Comment: I couldn't find where they don't recommend it. (their example using a hierarchy in the name isn't valid in the first place, that lacks of flexibility) It's basically the only option to cross the boundaries. Or what would be the alternative?

Comment: It's there in chapter 2, and in xilinx forum. They recommend using full hierarchical names for get_cells at different hierarchical level: like */*/example_reg, if wildcards have to be used to filter cells. Instead of using "-hierarchical example_reg". Otherwise Synthesiser misses timing paths to example_regs which are in hierarchical netlist. Basically this happens if flattened hierarchy is disabled while synthesis. Otherwise no problems.

Comment: I'm not using `/` in my destination reg (`*_reg*`) then there is no way of mixing things up between actual hierarchy and flattened names. You can use hierarchical level only if you know them in advance. I hate anything hard-coded. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: You are welcome :)